# Get tuple of values from nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

I'm trying to create a python script that goes through a dict with a structure similar to:

```py
structure = {
    'key1' : {'keyA' : 'valueA1', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC1', 'keyD': 'valueD1'}},
    'key2' : {'keyA' : 'valueA2', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC2', 'keyD': 'valueD2'}},
    'key3' : {'keyA' : 'valueA3', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC3', 'keyD': 'valueD3'}}
}
```

and returns a tuple, lets say, with every 'valueDX' element where X is 1, 2 or 3. I mean, return a tuple like

```
(valueD1, valueD2, valueD3)
```

I tried doing

```
my_list = []
for x in structure.values():
    my_list.append(x['keyB'].values()['keyD'])
```

But I have the following error:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Do you want to search a recursive dictionary structure for any values matching some pattern?

Comment: `structure` is not a valid python dict

Comment: You will need to fix your syntax error(s) before you get a TypeError

Answer (score 0):

```
   your_list=[]
   for x1 in structure.values():
      try:
         your_list.append(x1['keyB']['keyD'])
      except:
         pass   # it better use try when dealing dict or unknown structure
   return your_list
```

you don't have use values() methods to get specific value.
it for dict values iteration.

Answer (score 0):

can do it in one liner as long as the keys are the same with every dict and always exist:

```
my_list = [v['keyB']['keyD'] for k,v in structure.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
tuple([structure[key]["keyB"]["keyD"] for key in structure.keys()])
# ('valueD1', 'valueD2', 'valueD3')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dict.get()

```
your_list=[]
for x1 in structure.values():
    your_list.append(x1.get('keyB').get('keyD'))

print(tuple(your_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dictionary-view-objects) `dict`-methods like `values`, `keys` return a *dictionary-view-objects*. This doesn't provide a direct access to its content as for list, tuple, ... but only iterate through it.

```
d = {1: 'A'}
print(type(d.values()))
#dictionary-view-objects

# casting the view
print(list(d.values())[0])
#A

# direct access to values of the view raise an error 
try:
   d.values()[0]
except TypeError:
   pass # TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Here a possible solution

```
structure = {
    'key1' : {'keyA' : 'valueA1', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC1', 'keyD': 'valueD1'} },
    'key2' : {'keyA' : 'valueA2', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC2', 'keyD': 'valueD2'}},
    'key3' : {'keyA' : 'valueA3', 'keyB' : {'keyC' : 'valueC3', 'keyD': 'valueD3'}}
}


my_list = []
key_levels = 'keyB', 'keyD'

for key_i in structure:
    d = structure[key_i]
    for key in key_levels:
        d = d[key]
    my_list.append(d)

my_list = tuple(my_list)
print(my_list)
```